# remove line break from boostrap tooltip

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a span tooltip that displays some information like: name and history.

I can separate this information with a `<br>`, but the tooltip is performing an automatic line break in the name.

How can I prevent the tooltip from performing this line break and only I, using `<br>`, can do this?

Image of the problem with an unwanted line break between "Xavier - Custodio"

[image]

Span code:

```
<span data-type="success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right" title="<%=txtTitle%>"><%=RsConsulta("servico")%></span>
```

=txtTitle :

```
txtTitle = "Released by: Thomas Neo Anderson"
txtTitle = txtTitle & "<br>History: Test for Example"
```

I'm using ASP Classic for Back-End

Comment: Please provide the relevant code in a stack snippet

Comment: What do you want to happen when the word is too long to fit on the current line, as appears to be the case in the image you have provided?

Comment: That the automatic line break does not occur, I would like the text to only be wrapped in the <br> tag

Comment: I'm trying to use the nowrap white-space in the title, but I still haven't had success. Would trying to style with CSS be the way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this CSS rule :

```css
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

```js
$("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip();
```

```css
.tooltip-inner {
  max-width: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<span data-type="success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-html="true" data-placement="right"  title="Line break wherever I want !<br/>Line break wherever I want. Line break wherever I want">test</span>
```

Comment: It worked beautifully @Tom! Thank you for your help! Thanks to the others for the directions too! https://imgur.com/dMVFOl4

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap variable `$tooltip-max-width: none;`